# how can I change a div class (html) with vbscript

Tags: html, vbscript, bots

I am coding a bot to interact with a page there is this checkbox that I need to check and the .click function won't work so I found it would be easier to change the class from "icheckbox_minimal" to "icheckbox_minimal checked"
But I have no idea how I can change that class with my VBS file Or is there another way to check the box?

I tried this, and it doesn't work
webbrowser.document.all.item("order_terms").click

This is The code of the checkbox

```
<div class="icheckbox_minimal" style="position: relative;">
   <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" name="order[terms]" 
   id="order_terms" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; 
   display:block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; 
   background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;">
   <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: 
   -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 
   0px;background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"></ins>
```

I just want the checkbox to be checked

Comment: Sounds like an X/y problem. What makes you think it is easier to click it if the class is changed?

Comment: Are there more than one `order_terms` ?

Comment: Also try `webbrowser.document.all.item("order_terms").InvokeMember("Click")`

Comment: @mplungjan If i change the class the checkbox gets checked, It works if I change it manually.

Comment: @mplungjan **Thank you for replying**, I tried searching for `order_terms` with ctrl+f in the html code and I only found one result

and if I use `webbrowser.document.all.item("order_terms").InvokeMember("Click")`
I get an error: _object doesn't support this propertt or method_

Comment: Perhaps items and 0? I do not do vbs

Comment: @mplungjan I'm also a beginner with vbs but What do you mean with _items and 0_

Comment: I Now also tried this, doesn't work unfortunately
`webbrowser.document.getElementsByClassName("icheckbox_minimal").classname = "icheckbox_minimal checked"`

Comment: That is because it returns a collection so also there you need an index

Comment: @mplungjan could you give an example of that index that I need to make??

Comment: Just add a [0] or (0) to the collection. Look up how the index a vb collection. I’m on my phone now

Comment: Use getElementById instead if there is only one

Comment: So this works in the cosole
`c = document.getElementsByClassName('icheckbox_minimal')[0]
c.className = 'icheckbox_minimal checked'`

But when it add webbrowser and put that in my vbs file it gives me an syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you @mplungjan**

I used this code (all in one line)

```
webbrowser.document.getElementsByClassName("icheckbox_minimal")(0).className = 
"icheckbox_minimal checked"
```

an it worked